# Should 'change profile picture' go on its own page or with Profile Information?

Tags: settings, user-preferences

I see that Facebook and other sites have the change profile picture on its own page. But, I don't know if I should add another tab to the already long settings tabs on the sidebar, so what is the most easiest set up for a user? I have it set up like this right now:

[image]

What would you recommend, it being on its own page or combined with the *Profile Information*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend you integrate it into the profile settings. However, I would suggest you move the "change profile picture" block upward to the top so it is more prominent on the page. As you have already said, you already have a large list of settings and I believe the "change profile picture" block is simple enough to not require its own tab.

Happy Coding